# How to get data from object in JSON response in Fragment

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, retrofit

How to get "description" from `GET` method in retrofit android with Fragment or `xml` and Retrofit interface and retrofit client ,full code actually i've face some issues.

I'm trying some time but i can't fix this `API`.

JSON response.

```
{
    "statuscode": 200,
    "status": "true",
    "cmsDetails": {
        "id": 2,
        "title": "Privacy Policy",
        "description": "<p>We, Devoid Technologies Pvt. Ltd., incorporated."
     }
}
```

Retrofit Interface

```
@GET("retrieve/policy")
Call<CMSDetails> getDescription();
```

I want get Description in cmsDetails object.

Comment: _"full code actually i've face some issues_" What issue?

Comment: show your `CMSDetails`

Answer (score 1):

Create a model for the JSON Response like this :

```
public class CMS
{
    @SerializedName("statuscode")
    private String statuscode;

    @SerializedName("status")
    private String status;

    @SerializedName("cmsDetails")
    private CmsDetails cmsDetails;

    public CmsDetails getCmsDetails()
    {   
        return cmsDetails;
    }
}
```

Now create another model for CmsDetails:

```
public class CmsDetails
{
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;

    @SerializedName("title")
    private String title;

    @SerializedName("description")
    private String description;

    public String getDescription()
    {
        return description;
    }
}
```

Now create your endpoint like this:

```
public interface EndPoints {
    @GET("retrieve/policy")
    Call<CMS> getDescriptionCms();
}
```

Now create the client as follows :

```
public class RetroFitCMSClient { 
    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static OkHttpClient okClient;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://test.test;

    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

        okClient = new OkHttpClient
                .Builder()
                .build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .client(okClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;

    }
}
```

Now you can make your call retrofit call and get the description like this :

```
EndPoints service = RetroFitCMSClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(EndPoints.class);
call = service.getDescriptionCms();
call.enqueue(new Callback<CMS>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<CMS> call, Response<CMS> response) {              
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                String description = response.body().getCmsDetails().getDescription();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<CMS> call, Throwable throwable) {
        }
}
```

Comment: But this is nor working on Fragment ,how to used inside fragment plz suggest me.